# NestJS return exception with array of errors

Tags: node.js, validation, exception, nestjs, grpc

Under the hood we use **yup** to validate **gRPC** requests that are sent to our application. We can get an array of errors, like:

```
message: [
      'filter.fieldOne must be one of the following values: 1, 2, 3',
      'filter.fieldTwo must not be one of the following values: 0'
]
```

We use custom *BaseRpcExceptionFilter* implementation:

```
@Catch()
export class AllRpcExceptionsFilter extends BaseRpcExceptionFilter {
  constructor(private readonly newRelicService: NewRelicService) {
    super();
  }

  catch(exception: Error, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    this.newRelicService.noticeError(exception, {
      exception: JSON.stringify(exception),
    });

    return super.catch(exception, host);
  }
}
```

And then we get this error message where these array of errors is passed as a string:

```
{
  "error": "3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: filter.executionSystem must be one of the following values: 1, 2, 3,filter.executionSystem must not be one of the following values: 0"
}
```

Is there any way to return it as an array instead of string object?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the code:

```
const errors = exception['response'].message.map((msg: string, index: number) => {
  const source = { pointer: msg.split(' ')[0] };
  return {
    id: uuidv4(),
    status,
    timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
    path: request.url,
    detail: msg,
    title: 'Bad Request',
    source,
  };
});

return response.status(status).json({
  errors,
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.